# To Restrict Duplicate values on blur action

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii

This is the screen shot of my application.

[image]

I have more than 70000 records in my db ,There is a chance for the end user to reenter the same data stored in db,Title is the unique field in my application .so i want to restrict the duplicate values of title on blur action.

For Example I have tested array of values with the input value of title like this

```
     <script>
     function myFunction()
     {  
      var names = <?php json_encode($test); ?>;
      var x=document.getElementById("title").value;  
      for (i=0; i < names.length; i++)
      { 
      if (x == names[i])
      { 
       alert("Duplicates Found");
      }    
      }     
      }
    </script>

    $test = array("title1","title2");
```

But i cannot do this comparison with the db values,Any Help will be appreciated..Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What if I turn off JS? I would recommend doing this server side also. As another point, that `for` loop will be really inefficient if there are 70,000 records to check.

Comment: Its AJAX validation. Enable client side validation and ajax validation. Add unique rule to attribute. Done.

Comment: I'd put a constraint on the database in which the Title field is unique. Then you can just fire the insert and catch if there is an error. Also you can use a query statement to select all titles with that tile, if the query returns a row, it already exists.

Comment: @FDL Ya using For loop will be inefficient thats y seeking help from u guys..

Comment: @ineersa Iam not good in ajax,if u can give me a exemple or hint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MESSIAH i believe this guy using yii. mysql? really? its deprecated already.

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE field=$parameter
```

This how unique check query must look like.
Dont use this ugly code please.

For example, this is how should look your form init:

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'feeds-form',
            'enableClientValidation' => true,
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,

            'clientOptions' => array(
                'validateOnSubmit' => true,))); ?>
```

In your controller use something like this:

```
if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
        {
            $error=CActiveForm::validate($model);
            if($error!='[]'){
                echo $error;
                Yii::app()->end();
                $flag=false;
            }
        }
```

It's perform ajax validation function in your case. You can add it to some new function or add at begining of your action.
To perform save use something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['Feeds'])&& ($_POST['ajax']!='feeds-form'))
//$model->save() or do whatever you want here
```

If you need full control on your errors and so on use ajaxSubmitButton:

```
 <?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save', Yii::app()->request->url, array(
                'dataType' => 'json',
                'type' => 'post',
                'success' =>
                'js:function (data) {

                 if(!$.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                      $.each(data, function(key, val) {//adding errors to error div wrapper here
                                $("#feeds-form #"+key+"_em_").text(val+" ");
                                $("#feeds-form #"+key+"_em_").parent(".error_wrapter").addClass("error");
                                $("#feeds-form #"+key+"_em_").css(\'display\',\'block\');
                                      });
                  };
                 if(data.status=="success"){
                                           hideAllMessages();
                                          setTimeout(function(){
                                            $(\'.\'+\'success_not\').fadeOut(700);
                                          },6000);
                                            $(\'.\'+\'success_not\').fadeIn({top:"0", left:"0"}, 700);
                                        }
                else {
                      hideAllMessages();
                       setTimeout(function(){$(\'.\'+\'fail\').fadeOut(700);},6000);
                    $(\'.\'+\'fail\').fadeIn({top:"0", left:"0"}, 700);
                  };
                  }',
            ), array(
                'id' => 'feeds-form_submit_' . rand(1, 255), // Need a unique id or they start to conflict with more than one load.
            ));?>
```

in your model you need to have rule for your title:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('title', 'unique'),
              ..............
        );
    }
```

Now its done.

Here is tip if you dont understand something.
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/37075-form-validation-with-ajaxsubmitbutton/

Comment: Ya ofcourse you are right Iam using yii and mysql..It will show up the warning when i press submit button right?But i want it as soon as title field is entered.Because it is waste of time to enter the other Fields if this title is already stored stored in db.I want to reduce the time..

Comment: No. It will show up after field loose focus(onchange). Read manual please and do it, then ask. It works in my projects perfectly.

Comment: I dont know where Iam going wrong i cant save the values in db and i cant get validation too ...let me try my best

Comment: Here is my gists. maybe it will help. View - https://gist.github.com/ineersa/5917325 . Controller - https://gist.github.com/ineersa/5917363

Comment: Thank you for your help i dont know why its not working but i found a simple method to achieve the solution it is appended to your code,I hope it may help some one,its working for me .Thank u once again...

Comment: No problem mate. Do how you like, i like to make `performajaxvalidation()` in my action, cause sometimes i have complex forms with 3-4 models, and converting `$model->validate()` to json response. `validateonsubmit` prevent submit with errors on form. I like to do it with `ajaxsubmitButton` to show custom errors and flashes(but its doable with normal submit). `$_POST['ajax']!='feeds-form'` added to post verify preevnts double save in this case. Anyway do how you want.

Comment: Ok Thank u mate If u can accept my edit also so it may help others.

Comment: Nah i cant. Its rejected not by me, and dont have enough rep.

Comment: If u can add by your own $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'entry-form',
       'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
       'enableClientValidation'=>true,
       'focus'=>array($model,'title'),
       
));